# webbrowser user data dir opens different browser environment (python selenium )

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I am working with python and selenium to set up a webscraper. I used the ChromeOptions module to open the chrome browser with a specific chrome user I have created. User name is: run_scraper_run. After creating the user a desktop connection has been created. I checked the desktop connection for the profile directory and copied the respective directory path. When I run the script it opens a browser but it seems like it opens another instance of google chrome. There is neither my default account selectable nor the one I created for the scraper. It seems like a separate environment if I can say that in that case. Does anyone have an idea what could have gone wrong or how I can get the created user account to be used?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\run_scraper_run')
options.add_argument('----profile-directory="run_scraper_run"')
ser = Service(r'C:\[PATH OF CHROMEDRIVER]')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, service = ser)
```

**This is my actual environment:**

[image]

**But this opens instead despite the same path as in the desktop icon properties**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the wrong user data directory path.

The user data directory path that you provide is actually the Profile path.
The following change should fix the issue:

```
options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
options.add_argument('----profile-directory="run_scraper_run"')
```

P.S. Verify that the Profile Directory name is correct. You can do this by checking that by accessing `chrome://version` in the chrome browser having the desired profile.